# Mobile site isn't adjusting to my screen width

Tags: support, mobile-web

Today, I have faced a problem: All of mobile pages aren't displayed with adjusted width against my screen width. I need to scroll horizontally to see everything.

The pages are loaded fine for the first time, then it automatically pulls something from server or process something (progress bar is triggered) which is causing this.

**Update:**
I am facing this problem with all web browsers on my Android 2.3.5 device except Opera Mobile. Here are screenshots:

Dolphin Browser
[image] [image]
[image] [image]

Stock Browser
[image] [image]

Maxthon Browser
[image] [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem isn't from SE side. After investigation, I have found that my ISP is modifying webpages to add its own javascript based ads. This Javascript code is causing such problem. Almost all non-HTTPS websites are victims.

AsiaNet and many other ISPs are doing such nasty things. I am going to sue my ISP for that.

To solve it, I have put `ui.streamride.net` and `streamride.net` to host file in my PCs, tablets and smartphones pointing to `127.0.0.1`.

If your Android device isn't rooted, there's no way to edit host file. But, you can do other tricks like pulling webpages using VPNs.

Comment: `I am going to sue my ISP for that.` Is that just an uttered phrase, a joke or reality?

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby Its reality. I gave them chance by calling customer care, but they didn't listen. Now, they'll have to answer in the court.

Comment: @SachinShekhar may the odds be ever in your favor.

Comment: Good luck and keep us up to date!